# Numerical Analysis Stability or Condition

Tags: numerical-methods, data-analysis

Im not sure if its the right place to ask this question since it may be more of an informatics problem and I apologize if its the case:

I want to evaluate a certain function, $\frac{log(cos(x))}{x}$ on the interval $[0;10^{-7}]$
,
I know that the function is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2x}log(1-sin^{2}(x))$ but when I draw them on matlab, on this interval, I get this[image]

The red line is the $\frac{1}{2x}log(1-sin^{2}(x))$ form of the function, the blue line the $\frac{log(cos(x))}{x}$ form.

How can one explain this, do I have one form more well-conditionned than the other? Is it a stability problem?

Comment: ln cos x is not defined when x < 0.  ln |cos x| = 1/2 ln (1-sin^2 x).  When x is small, ln cos x ~ -1/2 x^2.  ln cos x / x ~ -1/2 x.  However, your two functions should equal one another.

Comment: You can try, thats the graph that comes, there is something wrong, but I dont know what, thats what Im trying to figure out

Comment: Try the `log1p` function i.e. use `log1p(-sin(x)^2)`. For small argument the direct $\ln(1\pm x)$ cannot be computed accurately with floating point (remember that for $x$ smaller than the machine $\epsilon$ you have $1+x=1$).

Comment: Can we say that it is a stability or ill-condition problem of the function with the log(1-sine²)?